# What does a generic type before the type name in a constructor call mean?

Tags: java

What does the code mean like this?

`new <Number>ArrayList()`

I know the correct way to write it like this

`new ArrayList<Number>()`

The first is not a generic, but what does it mean?

Comment: oh, so it does not mean anything?@Shabbir

Comment: It is still generics, but on a different level. The first is a generic type parameter for the constructor itself, while the second is a generic type parameter of the ArrayList type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the type argument of function `new`

```java
    // Different type is semantic bad but good for testing the AST
    final List<String> ls = new<Integer> ArrayList<Double>();
```

AST:

```java
{
    "node": "VariableDeclarationFragment",
    "name": {
        "identifier": "ls",
        "node": "SimpleName"
    },
    "extraDimensions": 0,
    "initializer": {
        "arguments": [],
        "anonymousClassDeclaration": null,
        "node": "ClassInstanceCreation",
        "type": {
            "node": "ParameterizedType",
            "type": {
                "node": "SimpleType",
                "name": {
                    "identifier": "ArrayList",
                    "node": "SimpleName"
                }
            },
            "typeArguments": [
                {
                    "node": "SimpleType",
                    "name": {
                        "identifier": "Double",
                        "node": "SimpleName"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "typeArguments": [
            {
                "node": "SimpleType",
                "name": {
                    "identifier": "Integer",
                    "node": "SimpleName"
                }
            }
        ],
        "expression": null
    }
}
```

Comment: i see, ty for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

These are the type arguments to a [generic constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.4)

> A generic constructor declaration defines a set of constructors, one for each possible invocation of the type parameter section by type arguments. Type arguments may not need to be provided explicitly when a generic constructor is invoked, as they can often by inferred

You can have generic constructors for non-generic classes, and generic constructors for generic classes that do not share a generic type with their class.

Comment: i see, ty for the answer.